# Use button on headset

Tags: drivers, sound, programming, headset

I have a headset which has a button that is supposed to play/pause audio, answer calls, etc. and I wanted to make it work on Ubuntu.
My computer does have a combined headset port (fourth lead), but when I press the button (which changes the impedance on the microphone) all it does is this:
[image: impedance change]
Is there any existing way to handle this and/or act upon it in Ubuntu?
If not, where should I start?

P.S. [Here](https://mega.nz/#!t3h0BAxD!wPo8Gg8pawgwq7vXwJleD9sJ48g_V6qC8M6tZIs1l6I) is the audio file

Answer (score 1):

The button works by shorting the microphone pin to ground. Headsets which have more buttons use different resistances between the mic pin and ground; see https://source.android.com/devices/accessories/headset/plug-headset-spec

This is only going to work if the codec chip in your audio device supports detecting those events — the hardware has to support it, and the software has to use it too, of course. Some Linux codec drivers do, and they create a new input device for the microphone jack, with "keypresses" corresponding to the four possible events. It's then up to software to determine double-clicks, long presses and stuff like that. But none of the Intel HDA codec drivers support this, and that's probably what you're using. I don't know if the *hardware* supports it and the driver could be augmented. What codec chip do you have?

Comment: My sound chip is `Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller (rev 09)`